# cannot use variable which is declared in helper function

Tags: php, laravel

helper.php

```
<?php

 function h()
{
    $randomchar = str_shuffle('abcdefghjklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ234567890!$%^&!$%^&');
            $password = substr($randomchar, 0, 12);
            $generated_pass = $password;
}
```

view

```
        <input type="text" id="lname" name="pass" value="<?php echo $generated_pass;?>"><br><br>
```

> error ErrorException
> PHP 8.1.12
> 9.48.0
> Undefined variable $generated_pass

tried to do it like above but got error.

Comment: ... start giving your time to docs and learn how does a function work and how to return data from a fn.

Answer (score 3):

functions should return its local value:

```
function h()
{
    $randomchar = str_shuffle('abcdefghjklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ234567890!$%^&!$%^&');
    return substr($randomchar, 0, 12);
}
```

then you should call function:

```
<input type="text" id="lname" name="pass" value="<?php echo h();?>"><br><br>
```